# No qualifying bean of type 'repository.Dao' available

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate

When I run this code it was shows this kind of error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'orderController': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through method 'setOrderService' parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'orderServiceImpl' defined in file
>   [C:\projects\crudmvc\out\artifacts\crudmvc_war_exploded\WEB-INF\classes service\OrderServiceImpl.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'repository.Dao' available: expected
>   at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency
>   annotations: {}       at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:719)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:397)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1429)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
>         at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
>         at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
>         at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
>         at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
>         at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4699)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5165)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1720)
>         at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)       at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)       at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
>         at
>   java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
>         at
>   java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:479)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:428)
>         at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)       at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)       at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
>         at
>   java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
>         at
>   java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>         at
>   java.management/com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
>         at
>   java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
>         at
>   java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
>         at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method)       at
>   java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1406)
>         at
>   java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:827)
>         at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)       at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)       at
>   java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
>         at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
>         at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
>         at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method)       at
>   java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
>         at
>   java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
>         at
>   java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
>         at
>   java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
>         at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method)       at
>   java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
>         at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>         at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)  Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'orderServiceImpl' defined in file
>   [C:\projects\crudmvc\out\artifacts\crudmvc_war_exploded\WEB-INF\classes\service\OrderServiceImpl.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'repository.Dao' available: expected
>   at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency
>   annotations: {}       at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:787)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:226)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:711)
>         ... 61 more     Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'repository.Dao' available: expected
>   at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/general")
public class OrderController {
    private OrderService orderService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("orderServiceImpl")
    public void setOrderService(OrderService orderService) {
        this.orderService = orderService;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/list")
    public String get(Model theModel) {

        theModel.addAttribute("orders", orderService.getOrders());

        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/showFormForAdd")
    public String add(Model theModel) {
        Orders orders = new Orders();

        theModel.addAttribute("order", orders);

        return "create-orders";
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/saveOrders")
    public String addOrders(@ModelAttribute Orders orders, @RequestParam MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        orders = orderService.uploadOrders(orders, file);
        orderService.save(orders);

        return "redirect:/general/list";
    }
}
```

Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Orders {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private int price;

    @Column(name = "sold")
    private boolean sold;

    @Column(name = "body")
    private String body;

    @Column(name = "brand")
    private String brand;

    @Column(name = "engine")
    private String engine;

    @Column(name = "model")
    private String model;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "image")
    private byte[] image;

    @Column(name = "imageStr")
    private String imageStr;


    public Orders() {
    }

    public Orders(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public boolean isSold() {
        return sold;
    }

    public void setSold(boolean sold) {
        this.sold = sold;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public String getEngine() {
        return engine;
    }

    public void setEngine(String engine) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public byte[] getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(byte[] image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getImageStr() {
        return imageStr;
    }

    public void setImageStr(String imageStr) {
        this.imageStr = imageStr;
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface Dao extends CrudRepository<Orders, Long>{

}
```

OrderService:

```
public interface OrderService {
    List<Orders> getOrders();

    Orders uploadOrders(Orders orders, MultipartFile file) throws IOException;

    void save(Orders orders);
}
```

OrderServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class OrderServiceImpl implements OrderService {

    private Dao dao;


    @Autowired
    public OrderServiceImpl(Dao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Orders> getOrders() {
        return Lists.newArrayList(dao.findAll());
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Orders orders) {
        dao.save(orders);
    }

    @Override
    public Orders uploadOrders(Orders orders, MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            String uploadDir = file.getOriginalFilename();

            orders.setImage(file.getBytes());
            orders.setImageStr(uploadDir);
        }

        return orders;
    }
}
```

spring-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
         https://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <import resource="hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
    <bean id = "dao" class ="repository.Dao" abstract="true"/>

    <context:component-scan
            base-package="
        controller
        repository
        service">
    </context:component-scan>

</beans>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="url"/>
        <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
        <property name="password" value="root"/>

    </bean>



    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="models"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myTransactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager"/>


</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Do you use spring boot?

Comment: Not spring boot

Comment: But you try to use spring data jpa: `interface Dao extends CrudRepository<Orders, Long>`?

Comment: How do you pack your application? Is it ear, war?

Comment: Yes, i want to use spring data jpa. i pack it in war.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i added code in hibernate.cfg.xml like this:

```
  <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="url"/>
        <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
        <property name="password" value="root"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="models" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />

        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="persistenceProvider">
            <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"></bean>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="repository" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />
```

Also i added in OrderServiceImpl class this:

```
@Resource
private Dao dao;
```

And now there are no errors and everything works